# Docker volume backup and restore postgres:10 image & named volume

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, volume, docker-volume

I'm trying to backup/restore a docker volume. This volume is a named volume attached to a `postgres:10` db image. The volume is seeded via a `pg_dump/restore`. I'm using `docker-compose` and here is what it looks like:

```yaml
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:10
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  volumes:
    postgres-data:
      driver: local
    localstack-data:
      driver: local
```

Here is what the mounted volume looks like on the db service:

```
"Mounts": [
    {
      "Type": "volume",
      "Name": "postgres-data",
      "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/postgres-data/_data",
      "Destination": "/var/lib/postgresql/data",
      "Driver": "local",
      "Mode": "rw",
      "RW": true,
      "Propagation": ""
    }
  ]
```

Now, when I say "backup/restore", I mean I want to be able to have a backup of the data inside that volume so that after I have messed all the data up, I can simply just replace it with the backup and have fresh data. A simple "restore w/ snapshot" type of action. I'm following the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes) found on docker.

To test it:

- I add a user to my `postgres-data`
- Stop my container `docker stop $(docker ps -q)`
- Perform backup (db_1 is container name): `docker run --rm --volumes-from db_1 -v $(pwd):/backup busybox tar cvf /backup/backup.tar /var/lib/postgresql/data`
- Delete user after backup is complete

Here is an example of the output of backup command that follows w/ NO errors:

```
tar: removing leading '/' from member names
var/lib/postgresql/data/
var/lib/postgresql/data/PG_VERSION
var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf
var/lib/postgresql/data/lib/
var/lib/postgresql/data/lib/postgresql/
var/lib/postgresql/data/lib/postgresql/data/
var/lib/postgresql/data/lib/postgresql/data/PG_VERSION
var/lib/postgresql/data/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf
var/lib/postgresql/data/lib/postgresql/data/lib/
var/lib/postgresql/data/lib/postgresql/data/lib/postgresql/
var/lib/postgresql/data/lib/postgresql/data/lib/postgresql/data/
var/lib/postgresql/data/lib/postgresql/data/lib/postgresql/data/PG_VERSION
var/lib/postgresql/data/lib/postgresql/data/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf
var/lib/postgresql/data/lib/postgresql/data/lib/postgresql/data/pg_stat/
```

Once done, tar file gets created. Now, maybe the error is with the path? If you look at the output I'm seeing `lib/postgresql/data` nested over and over. Not sure if that is an okay result or not.

Once done, I perform the "restore": `docker run --rm --volumes-from db_1 -v $(pwd):/backup busybox sh -c "cd /var/lib/postgresql/data && tar xvf /backup/backup.tar --strip 1"`

What I expect: To see the deleted user back in the db. Basically, to see the same data that was in the volume when I performed the backup.
What I'm seeing: the data is not getting restored. Still same data. No user restored and any data that has been changed stays changed.

Again, perhaps what I'm doing is the wrong thing or "overkill" for a simple desire to hot swap out used volumes with a fresh, untouched one. Any ideas would be helpful from debugging or a better approach.

Comment: So what is your actual problem?

Comment: @TheFool Updated the question a little as I can see I wasn't quite clear on the actual problem. It is that simply the backup volume isn't getting restored. At least, the user doesn't get restored and the data that was originally changed is still changed.

Comment: I can imagine Postgres doesn't like it much if you change the filesystem by hand it's using while it's running. I could see it ending up corrupting its state somehow. Apart from that, I think a proper backup should happen at the storage of the host. Like you would back up your whole data disk or block storage. But that's not really your question. Technically, there should be an answer to your question.

Comment: I'm not sure this has really anything to do w/ Postgres being that its just file swapping on a volume. Which I imagine is what `pg_dump/restore` is doing. Unless I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: at least pg dump generates sql statements on dump. To get the data back in, you actually use a normal pg client and tell it to run those statements in the dump file.